# Word that means a "slow and painful transformation"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, adjectives, phrasal-verbs

I'd like to describe a process of change that is both slow and painful for those involved using a verb or phrasal verb (heck, throw me an adjective if you have one, no complaints). Is there a word that could capture this sentiment?

Comment: Your phrase “slow and painful” sounds like it would work. Consider adding a sample sentence to your question to provide context for why it doesn’t work in your case, and to help the community find an appropriate replacement.

Comment: How about "metamorphosis"?

Comment: excrutiating, for an adjective